# Difficulty in analyzing the encryption algorithm

Tags: java, image-processing, encryption

I have developed an encryption algorithm based on DCT and Lagrange's Interpolation technique in Java. Now, I have to compare the algorithm with native algorithms like blowfish/AES/DES . I have downloaded the source of above algorithms and tried to get the encrypted and corresponding decrypted images. But the encrypted image is in such a format that they are not readable. Neither the windows photo viewer, picasa, etc read them. Then I tried to open it in matlab, but it said that it doesn't recognize the image. But the same image is successfully decrypted to original image.
I need the encrypted images such that I can find Histogram, entropy, NCPR, UACI, correlation coefficients on that. So please suggest me on this!

Comment: You seem to think that encrypting an image will result in a sequence of bytes that represent a valid image. It won't. An encrypted image is a sequence of bytes that can't be read by anything. The only meaningful thing you can do with this sequence of bytes is to decrypt it to get back the original image bytes.

Comment: Your best plan might be to use a bitmap image, encrypt the raw image data but leave the header data alone.  I am not 100% sure, but I think that will still display (that the encryption will not take any bytes or set of bytes outside an allowed and display-able range for BMP).

Comment: " can find Histogram, entropy, NCPR, UACI, correlation coefficients on that...". You don't need a viewer to do any of that, just treat the encrypted image file as a file of binary data.